# Property 'toJSON' does not exist on type 'Auth'.ts(2339) firebase && typescript (server side)

Tags: typescript, postgresql, google-oauth, prisma, firebase-admin

I'm trying to complete the Google login process via Firebase using typescript, prisma and firebase-admin but when I try to get the user who wants to log in I get the error mentioned above
Note: I don't know if my method is correct.

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
import appConfig from '@/AppConfig/app.config';
export const setupFirebase = () => {
  admin.initializeApp({ projectId: appConfig.firebaseProjectID });
};

export const firebase = admin;
code2:
import { type Response, type NextFunction, type Request } from 'express';
import UserService from './users.service';
import Api from '@/lib/api';
import { firebase } from '@/lib/firebase';
export default class UserController extends Api {
  private readonly userService = new UserService();

  public createUser = async (
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ) => {
    try {
      // Get the firebase user data
      const firebaseUser = firebase.auth();
      const userData = firebaseUser.toJSON();

      // Check if the user already exists in the database
      const existingUser = await this.userService.findUserByEmail(
        userData.email
      );
      if (existingUser) {
        // Update the existing user's data
        res.json('User already exist');
      } else {
        // Create a new user record
        await this.userService.createUser(
          userData.name,
          userData.email,
          userData.photoUrl
        );
      }

      // Send a success response with the user's data
      res
        .status(200)
        .json({ message: 'User created successfully', user: userData });
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  };
}
```

I expect to get the user data and save it in the database and complete the login process with google and firebase properly.

If anyone knows how to complete the process I am trying to do please let me know.

Comment: The message *Property 'toJSON' does not exist on type 'Auth'.ts* is pretty clear. This:`const firebaseUser = firebase.auth(); const userData = firebaseUser.toJSON();` is failing as `firebase.auth()` does not have the `toJSON` property.

Comment: Well, what should the code look like to take a user value and put it in the database.

Comment: I have no idea as I don't use Firebase. You will need to read the docs and find out what `firebaseUser = firebase.auth();` does provide.